# How can I mock private static method with PowerMockito?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I'm trying to mock private static method `anotherMethod()`. See code below

```
public class Util {
    public static String method(){
        return anotherMethod();
    }

    private static String anotherMethod() {
        throw new RuntimeException(); // logic was replaced with exception.
    }
}
```

Here is me test code

```
@PrepareForTest(Util.class)
public class UtilTest extends PowerMockTestCase {

        @Test
        public void should_prevent_invoking_of_private_method_but_return_result_of_it() throws Exception {

            PowerMockito.mockStatic(Util.class);
            PowerMockito.when(Util.class, "anotherMethod").thenReturn("abc");

            String retrieved = Util.method();

            assertNotNull(retrieved);
            assertEquals(retrieved, "abc");
        }    
}
```

But every tile I run it I get this exception

```
java.lang.AssertionError: expected object to not be null
```

I suppose that I'm doing something wrong with mocking stuff. Any ideas how can I fix it?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

To to this, you can use `PowerMockito.spy(...)` and `PowerMockito.doReturn(...)`.

Moreover, you have to specify the PowerMock runner at your test class, and prepare the class for testing, as follows:

```
@PrepareForTest(Util.class)
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
public class UtilTest {

   @Test
   public void testMethod() throws Exception {
      PowerMockito.spy(Util.class);
      PowerMockito.doReturn("abc").when(Util.class, "anotherMethod");

      String retrieved = Util.method();

      Assert.assertNotNull(retrieved);
      Assert.assertEquals(retrieved, "abc");
   }
}
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: If you already specified a Class with the PowerMock runner add the second one like this: `@PrepareForTest({First.class, Util.class})`

Comment: String retrieved = **Util.anotherMethod();** The name of the static method is not _method_ it is **anotherMethod**.

Comment: @Stevers method() is the public static method invoked from the test. anotherMethod() is the mocked method. The answer is correct, please check again the OP.

Comment: solution does not really mention what is wrong with the original solution. The original solution is using a mock, which means an entire fake object, where the methods are not defined. The author only defines for method "anotherMethod" how it should behave when it is called. But he does not define the same way for method "method". That is the reason why calling "method" returns null and never even gets to call "anotherMethod". Using a spy we are using the real object and all methods are the real methods. Another solution would be using mock and use .callRealMethod for the "method".

Answer (score 10):

If anotherMethod() takes any argument as anotherMethod(parameter), the correct invocation of the method will be:

```
PowerMockito.doReturn("abc").when(Util.class, "anotherMethod", parameter);
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure what version of PowerMock you are using, but with the later version, you should be using `@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(Util.class)`

Saying this, I find using PowerMock to be really problematic and a sure sign of a poor design. If you have the time/opportunity to change the design, I would try and do that first.

Comment: No. For `TestNG` I need use my annotations.

Comment: A note for those who need to use a different runner and thus cannot use the PowerMockRunner, you can instead use the @Rule annotation:
```
@Rule
    public PowerMockRule rule = new PowerMockRule();
```