# Intercepting method calls in Java with mockito or proxies

Tags: java, testing, junit

I'd like to know if there is a way to intercept class method call that contacts the server and returns configuration settings for my application and then return required value for my test. My application looks like this

```
package application;

class Application { 
  private static synchronized void getServerConfiguration() {
      ConfigurationAccessor accessor = new ConfigurationAccessor();
      optionOne = accessor.getOption("option-one"); // <- intercept this method call and return different value
      ...
  }
}
```

In my tests I need to use a running instance of the application to run GUI tests :

```
package tests;

class SomeTest {

@BeforeClass public static void startApplication() {
  createUsers();
  Application.start(); <- this will start application and load config from server
}
```

Unfortunately it's not possible to run connection via proxy server to mock responses.

Comment: You could do so by using PowerMockito. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25594090/how-can-i-mock-private-static-method-with-powermockito) should be a good nod in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

If you inject the ConfigurationAccessor into the Application class, you would be able to inject a mock in SomeTest. I.e. create a constructor

```
Application(ConfigurationAccessor accessor) {
    this.accessor = accessor;
}
```

then in your test you would be able to

```
Application target;
@Mock
ConfigurationAccessor accessorMock;
@Before
public void setUp() {
    target = new Application(accessorMock);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately i can't make changes to Application class. It's a huge pile of legacy code that i dont know how it still works