# Test Config class with multiple private final fields

Tags: java, unit-testing, design-patterns

How would you suggest to "fix" this class for better testing?

```
public class Config {
    private final ComplexA complexA;
    private final ComplexB complexB;
    (...)

    Config(String[] args) {
         complexA = privateMethodCalculatesA(args);
         complexB = privateMethodCalculatesB(args);
         (...)
    }
}
```

Now, all methods that calculate `complexA/B/...` are intended to fail-fast if user inserts non-existing or wrong parameters with a `System.exit`.  The issue here is that `Config` becomes mangled with methods that should be tested in isolation.

Nonetheless same methods should not be publicly exposed and result should be cached as calculation may be expensive.

Just hit the bullet and declare said methods `static protected` and test them in isolation?

What would be the proper way to do this?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25594090/how-can-i-mock-private-static-method-with-powermockito

Comment: @user7294900 thks! It's useful, and already using on other tests but on this particular scenario, when initializing `Config` I'd be mocking a lot of private methods just to suppress them. And new variables would imply more private methods on the constructor which would invalidate previous tests. Is this really saner than going with `static protected` on those methods? Thanks for your time.

Comment: I'm not sure that changing code for a test is better, but it depends

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider separating `ComplexA`, `ComplexB`, etc. into their own classes. That solves the independent testing problem. Then you are faced with the problem of collecting the pieces into a whole. Likely you would favor composition over inheritance for that problem; but either approach might work.

Comment: Yes, I guess that would fix it. Thanks! Don't know why I was resisting the most straightforward path.